# google app engine render check box from database model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms

I am developing my first Google App Engine project and I think I am misunderstanding something fundamental about the database and form models. I have the following python code:

```
class RegData(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    forename = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
    interest = db.StringListProperty(choices=['TV','COMPUTING','SOCCER'])

class RegForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegData
```

What I want to do is have the form render the 'interest' property as a set of check boxes instead of a text area. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

from django import forms as form

you must add the above module in models.py

models.py

```
interest=(
            ('Tv', 'TV'),
            ('Computing', 'COMPUTING'),
            ('Soccer', 'SOCCER'),
                        )
class RegData(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    forename = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
    interest = db.StringListProperty()

class RegForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    interest= form.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=interest)
    class Meta:
        model = RegData
```

RegData is the table in your database (entity)  , RegForm is that the user will see this form on your page.

main.py

```
class ShowForm(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        show(self)
    def post(self):
        show(self)

 def show(self):
    get = self.request.GET
    post = self.request.POST


    data = models.RegData()

    if post:
        form = models.RegForm(data=post, instance=RegDate)

        if form.is_valid():
            entity = form.save(commit=False)
            entity.put()

    else:
        form = models.RegForm(instance=RegDate)
```